# Query string in client side

Tags: query-string, client-side, request.querystring

I am a beginner in using ASP.NET and JavaScript. I've stumbled upon this problem:

1. In my `page1.aspx`, I use `Response.Redirect("page1.aspx#download")` using an anchor.
2. Now, I want to get the `Request.QueryString` upon loading on the client side using JavaScript.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: @Jules Mazur Can you help he with my problem? Anyway, thanks for editing my post.

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience with ASP; I'm more of a JSP web app developer.

Answer (score 0):

page1.aspx#download

By the above declaration you will not be able to get this Download as a text on other page. You need to declare it like this

page1.aspx?Value=download

and on page1.aspx server side you need to get the value by calling

lblText.Text = Request.QueryString["Value"];

lblText will be asp:label on client side of this page and you can call it on page load so your value will be diplayed.